# Internal Oauth 2.0 Jwt tokens for external application

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, authorization, keycloak

Hello we are currently using Keycloak as our authentication server and we provide access to our users  using the Resource owner password credential flow (we know this is legacy and we are upgrading to authorisation flow).

Now we have a requirement where we will need to provide users who will sign in externally into our system from an external third party application.
Since the users will be our own, we are thinking of using the OAuth 2.0 authorisation flow, to provide tokens to the external application.

The external client is a trusted client and part of the same larger organisation but the auth servers are different and the users are different
,so there won’t be a single signon.

My question is if it is a good practice to expose the same access token, which is used internally to this external application.  Or should we have some kind of separate internal and external tokens ?